# Is there a way to export chartjs-chart-treemap?

Tags: javascript, node.js, export, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I'm using a **chart.js** extension called: **chartjs-chart-treemap** but i'm having trouble exporting the chart. I have tried using **chartjs-node-canvas** but this library only supports native **chart.js** charts (non-extension charts).

Does anyone know a library or a way to export **chart.js** extensions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. In order for **chartjs-node-canvas** to understand the type **treemap**, some custom configurations are required to be added.

Source: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/charts.html#extending-existing-chart-types

Answer (score 2):

chartjs-node-canvas will use Chart.js plugins that have been imported into the global namespace.

Just import it like this:

```
const chartTreeMap = require('chartjs-chart-treemap');
const { CanvasRenderService } = require('chartjs-node-canvas');
```

And use CanvasRenderService normally.  You don't have to do anything with the `chartTreeMap` object as it automatically overrides chart on import (see [source code](https://github.com/kurkle/chartjs-chart-treemap/blob/master/src/index.js#L10)).

Many of the treemap library examples reference a `Color` object.  You would have to replace that with `Chart.helpers.color` and also provide a global `CanvasGradient` object.